# Invalid CSRF tokenのエラーでログインができない。

Tags: php, symfony

Symfony2.3のシステムをSymfony3へアップデートし、動作を確認しております。
システムにログインしようとした際、下記メッセージが出てログインができない状態です。
このエラーが出る前に `csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager` を他ページのエラー解決のためsecurity.ymlに追加したことが原因と考えられますが、どのように下記エラーを解決すべきか分からない状態です。
解決策はありますか？

**Error message**

```
Invalid CSRF token.
```

**Code**

SecurityController.php

```
/**
 * 入力画面
 *
 * @Route("/login")
 * @Template("AhiSpAdminBundle:Security:login.html.twig")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    // ログイン済はTOPへリダイレクト
    if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_HQ_MANAGE')) {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ahi_sp_admin_hq_default_index', array(), UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL));
    } elseif ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_SHOP_STAFF')) {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ahi_sp_admin_shop_default_index', array(), UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL));
    }

    $session = $request->getSession();

    // ログインエラーがあれば、ここで取得
    if ($request->attributes->has(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } else {
        $error = $session->get(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }

    // エラーメッセージを取得
    $alertError = null;
    if ($error) {
        $alertError = $this->get('translator')->trans($error->getMessage());
    }

    return array(
        'last_username' => $session->get(Security::LAST_USERNAME),
        'alertError'    => $alertError,
    );
}
/**
 * スタッフをログイン状態にする
 *
 * @param Staff $staff スタッフエンティティ
 */
public function autoLogin($staff)
{
    $csrf_token = new UsernamePasswordToken($staff, $staff->getRawPassword(), 'secured_area', $staff->getRoles());
    $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($csrf_token);
}
```

login.html.twig

```
{% extends 'AhiSpAdminBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{# contentTitle #}
{% block contentTitle %}ログイン{% endblock %}

{# contentBody #}
{% block contentBody %}
    {# ログインフォーム #}
    <form method="post" action="{{ path('ahi_sp_admin_security_logincheck') }}" autocomplete="off" >

        {# TODO あとで修正する #}
        <table style="margin: 20px auto">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;color:red;">{{ alertError | nl2br }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>ログインID</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="username" name="_username" class="imeOff" value="{{ last_username }}"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>パスワード</label></td>
                <td><input type="password" id="password" name="_password"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-signin"></i> ログイン</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
                    <a href="{{ path("ahi_sp_admin_security_passwordforgot") }}">※パスワードを忘れた場合</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

security.yml

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    secured_area2:
        pattern:    ^/admin/sp/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path:  /admin/sp/login
            check_path:  /admin/sp/login_check
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path:            /admin/sp/
            target_path_parameter:          _target_path
            use_referer:                    false

        logout:
            path:   /admin/sp/logout
            target: /admin/sp/login

        remember_me:
            secret:      "%secret%"
            lifetime: 2592000 # 30 days in seconds
            path:     /
            domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
            always_remember_me: true
```

**実行環境:**
Cent OS 6.7
PHP 5.6
Symfony 3.0.9

Comment: ほかのページのエラー解決のためにCSRFのトークンオプションを追加したと記述していますが、このオプションの意味や目的は理解していますか？とりあえず入れただけだと今後も同じように問題が起きたときに対処が難しくなりそうです。

Comment: @keitaro_so 確かに理解が足りていない可能性は十分あるかもしれません。他のページでcsrfトークンを使用した場合、エラーが出ている箇所でもトークンを渡す必要がありますか。 https://symfony.com/doc/3.0/security/csrf_in_login_form.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

下記をlogin.html.twigに追加、OSの再起動で解決しました。
`<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token"　value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">`